# Need to find the Max value in a SQL table and Based on the MAX value need to generate the Id's

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

```
Member_Id    Interaction    Status
971053019         1          1
971053019         2          1
971053019         3          1
971053019         4          0
971053019         1          1
971053019         2          0
971053019         1          0
971053019         1          0
971053019         1          1
971053019         2          1
971053019         3          0
971053019         1          0
```

For the above table i need to generate the 1's to the status column

The key note here is..., we need to find the maximum value in the interaction column ...for that MAX value we need to update the status column as 0... and for the remaining rows it should be 1.

I have tried with SQL Aggregated Max Value function by doing grouping but i am unable to make the expected result set. Kindly any one help me with the SQL Script.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your results seem to depend on an ordering, so this question cannot be solved unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a kind of gaps-and-island problem. You want to set the flag on rows `interaction` is not greater that the "following" `interaction`.

For the question to make sense, you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows. This is not showing in your sample data, so I assumed `id`. Then, you can use `lead()`:

```
select 
    member_id,
    interaction,
    case when lead(interaction, 1, interaction) (over(partition by member_id order by id) > interaction     
        then 1 
        else 0 
    end as status
from mytable
```

Comment: Based on the interaction column Sequence set .. need to generate the Id's(1 or 0) for the STATUS column..**FOR EXAMPLE** In the above table the first four rows will be treated as one sequence set ..so in the first four rows the maximum value is 4 then for the 4 value we assigned 0 in the status column...  could you please suggest me an alternative approach

Comment: @Madhavenugopal: this is what the query does. Did you try it?

Comment: Yeah i have tried...so in the above table..if you see the last four rows the indicators for the last four rows are 1,2,3 so in this particular set the max value is 3 then for the 3 value we assigned 0 in the status column ...

Comment: @Madhavenugopal: ok, I think I misunderstood your question. I changed my answer.